# Keras Multi-GPU: One CPU core goes to 100% and system Hangs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been using the system with one GTX1080 Ti on my system for training. It was working fine. Recently added one more 1080 Ti and tried to use both using Keras multi_gpu model. Initially, the system got hang so I replaced CPU thermal cooler and CPU temperature remains below 50C. However, during the training process, one of the CPU cores goes to 100% usage and system stop to respond. Though, I can move the cursor but can't click. The situation is given here in this image.
[image]

Now, I have tried using only one GPU for the training but still issue remain there if I increase `max_queue_size` above 5 keeping `workers= 1` in `model.fit_generator(....)`

System Configuration: Core i7 4790 3.6 GHz, 32 GB

Comment: try reducing batch size - begin with 1 and go up if it runs smoothly

Comment: In that case, GPU utilization will remain below 30% and will need more training time than single GPU. I have reduced the size to 8 on one GPU then it does not hang. But two GPUs are of no use in the system.

Comment: you will have to provide some parts of the code - how do you initialize your model? it should be a multi gpu model i.e. `model = multi_gpu_model(network_model, gpus=2)` workers refer only to CPU

Comment: I know that. During training, if workers, queue and/or batch_size is decreased the CPU utilization decreases which reduces input to GPUs reducing processing.

Comment: well you will have to add your model initialization for us to help, imagine you were answering your question - there is one screenshot showing resource usage and vague description of the problem, no source code(best would be minimal and reproducible), from my experience the issue is too large batch_size that does not fit into gpu memory but I have no idea what shape is the data you are cramming ino the gpu - it might be too large to fit etc

Comment: The model is resnet34 (https://github.com/raghakot/keras-resnet). I have trained the same model on this system previously and another system which has GTX 1060 (6GB). With two GPUs it is behaving weird, I can understand why. 

The GPU RAM usage (ref: fig) is only 47% neither is a system RAM issue. All CPU cores are normal except one which is at 100%.